# SimpledateFormat's parse method java

Tags: java, parsing, date, date-format, simpledateformat

This is a silly question, but I can't see what I am doing wrong. I want to parse a string like `24:00` to a date object. I am aware that if we use `kk:mm` as the date format the times would be from 01:00 to 24:00 ([from the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). But I can't get the below code working.

```
String test = "24:00";
System.out.println("TEST: " + new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm").parse(test));
```

Output:

```
TEST: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970
```

Expected output:

```
TEST: Thu Jan 01 24:00:00 GMT 1970
```

**Edit:**

```
System.out.println("TEST: " + new SimpleDateFormat("k:mm:ss").format(new SimpleDateFormat("k:mm:ss").parse(test)));
```

this prints `TEST: Thu Jan 01 24:00:00 GMT 1970`

But why not while parsing?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to output "Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970" via "kk:mm" and you will see :)

Comment: @Fildor ofcourse, it works that way. but why not while parsing?

Comment: It does actually work. But the DateTime object cannot hold "24:00". It is 00:00 - 23:59. It will output 00:00 as 24:00 when formated with "k" but internally still be 00:00. It's a bit like using AM/PM or 24-hour. Internally represented the same - different output.

Comment: @Fildor ahh, now i understand.. tahnsk :)

Comment: I was actually a bit sloppy, +1 for @jalynn2's precise explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Date.toString() method is defaulting to hh:mm. Use SimpleDateFormat to output it as well as to parse it.

Comment: i dont want a string i want a date object

Comment: @chaitanya10: They dates are the same, it's just a question of how you want the output formatted.

Comment: The Date object uses a long to represent the time: number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01. WHen you parse it you get a date object with that number. The formatting turns that number into a human-readable string. You may request that the string is formatted where midnight="00:00", "24:00", or "12:00 AM". They are all just different representations of the same thing. Since you are not supplying a date, 00:00 = 24:00